# Python - urllib2 timeout

Tags: python, urllib2

I got something below is snippet of my code

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirect_handler.MyHTTPRedirectHandler())
opener.addheaders = [('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')]
fetch_timeout = 12
self.response = opener.open(url, timeout=fetch_timeout)
```

however, it code still waits 60~ seconds before timing out...
Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

At a guess you probably need to set the socket timeout

```
import socket

default_timeout = 12

socket.setdefaulttimeout(default_timeout)
```

Comment: +1 , I was in process of editing my answer when yours came in. This works for all versions.

Comment: Doesn't seem to want to work. Doing  socket.setdefaulttimeout(12) then print socket.getdefaulttimeout() says None This is 2.6.1 on OSX Snow Leopard

Answer (score 2):

Which version are you using. It was added in 2.6

Also the method is

```
urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])
```

Can you try providing

```
self.response = opener.open(url, None, fetch_timeout)
```

Yeah for all others, you could still use socket module to set socket time out.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [OpenerDirector](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#openerdirector-objects) class and the [urllib2.install_opener()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.install_opener) method.