# urllib2 timeout

Tags: python, timeout, urllib2

i'm using urllib2 library for my code, i'm using a lot of (urlopen) EDIT: loadurl

i have a problem on my network, when i'm browsing sites, sometimes my browser gets stuck on "Connecting" to a certain website and sometimes my browser returns a timeout

My question is if i use urllib2 on my code it can timeout when trying to connect for too long to a certain website or the code will get stuck on that line.

i know that urllib2 can handle timeouts without specifying it on code but it can apply for this kind of situation ?

Thanks for your time

EDIT :

```
def checker(self)
 try:
   html = self.loadurl("MY URL HERE")
   if self.ip_ != html:
(...)
 except Exeption, error:
   html = "bad"
```

Comment: are you opening url's in seperate threads ?

Comment: you can take a look at that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207983/python-urllib2-timeout

Comment: Hi aacanakin thanks for your reply
i have this on my code:

`code`
def checker(self)
 try:
   html = self.loadurl("MY URL HERE")
   if self.ip_ != html:
    (...)
 except Exeption, error:
   html = "bad"

Comment: That code excerpt does not use urllib2, but apparently some custom thing on top of it?

Answer (score 1):

from my small research, the `urllib2.urlopen()` function is added in python 2.6

so, the timeout problem should be resolved by sending custom timeout to the `urllib2.urlopen` function. the code should look like this ;

`response = urllib2.urlopen( "---insert url here---", None, your-timeout-value)`

the `your-timeout-value` parameter is an optional parameter which defines the timeout in seconds.

EDIT : According to your comment, I got that you don't need the code for waiting too long then you should have the following code to not get stuck;

```
import socket
import urllib2

socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
```

`10` can be changed according to a math formula related to the connection speed & website loading time.

Comment: The timeout parameter was added in Python 2.6; urllib2 and its urlopen exist longer.

Comment: Thank you for you reply
As far as i know if you don't specify timeout parameter it uses global default timeout, but the case of taking too long to load an existing website which it can resolve the DNS but got stuck on connecting can be handle by this global default timeout of urllib2 library ? 
i just need that the code don't get stuck on loading a website and proceed till the end

Comment: Moreover, if you have simultaneous (multi-threaded way) `urlopen()` , then some web servers may understand this as a DDOS attack and you may  get http errors from response from these requests.

Comment: @poke: It's just `urllib.request.urlopen` now.

Comment: @Mehrdad This question is about `urllib2` though, which is a Python 2 module. `urllib.request` is Python 3.