# Python urllib2 request timeout

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2

My code:

```
link = "http://www.google.com"
request_headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Referer": "http://google.com", "Connection": "keep-alive"}
request = urllib2.Request(link, headers=request_headers)
```

How can I add a timeout of five seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
```

(taken from [urllib2 timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148341/urllib2-timeout))

Comment: Is there no default timeout set by python?

Comment: I just tried `socket.getdefaulttimeout()` It returns `None` if you call it before `socket.setdefaulttimeout(value)`